# How to create a login-screen replacement for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, security, ubuntu, gtk, gnome

I'm interested in writing a replacement login screen for Ubuntu that would present the user with a puzzle rather than prompt for a password. I'm looking for some advice on how to go about creating this. I'm a programmer by profession with years of experience, but am not familiar enough with Linux application programming to know how to begin this particular project. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps a place to start is to implement a [pam](http://aplawrence.com/Basics/understandingpam.html) provider which stores the puzzle's solution in the home directory of the user.  That should actually do the login for you (similar to how the fingerprint readers work).  Then it's just creating the different prompts (login-screen, sudo, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do this as an authentication module for PAM (Linux Pluggable Authentication Modules). 
PAM is configured in configuration files in /etc/pam.d. Each file in this directory defines a PAM service by specifying a set of PAM modules and how they should work together. You could write a new authentication module and replace the current authentication module in the services where you want to use the new login scheme.

Answer (score 0):

The "best" way to do this may be to create a PAM module. This is how things like fingerprint identification are implemented. It will allow you to keep the same login screen with all the features such as accessibility options, etc.

The "easiest" way to do it may be to modify an existing display manager. Ubuntu uses GDM (Gnome Display Manager) by default, but it's pretty complicated. [SLiM](http://slim.berlios.de/) is a simple display manager that you can probably modify without much difficulty.